# ActionLink no me direcciona al controlador - MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Tengo mi siguiente ActionLink:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Requerimiento", "Index", "Almacen")</li>
```

el cual necesito direccionar a la vista Index del controlador almacen pero al dar click no funciona (al inpeccionar elemento si me carga el link de referencia)

```
<a href="/Almacen/Index" id="destinoLink">Requerimiento</a>.
```

NOTA: Es un menú desplegable (tipo acordeón que tiene trabajando un código en jquery) que es el siguiente:

```
(function ($) {
    $('.menu li:has(ul)').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if ($(this).hasClass('activado')) {

        } else {
            $('.menu li ul').slideUp('slow');
            $('.menu li').removeClass('activado');
            $(this).addClass('activado');
            $(this).children('ul').slideDown('slow');
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Cuando desactivo el uso de la función jQuery me funciona sin problemas el ActionLink....

Alguien que me pueda ayudar por favor.

Adicional código completo de mi menú:

**MENÚ PRINCIPAL**

```
            <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="icono izquierda fas fa-warehouse"></i> Almacén <i class="icono derecha fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
                <ul>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Requerimiento", "Index", "Almacen")</li> 
                    <li><a href="#">Abastecimiento</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Distribución</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="icono izquierda fas fa-money-check-alt"></i> Tesorería <i class="icono derecha fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Cobranza</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pagos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Liquidación</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="icono izquierda fas fa-shopping-bag"></i> Compras <i class="icono derecha fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Requerimiento</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: crees que puedas agregar todo el codigo del html de tu pagina? en tu pregunta

Comment: Listo, cuando doy click en el menú Requerimiento no me direcciona a : /Almacen/Index..... cuando quito el evento jQuery que utiliza mi menú normal de direcciona.

Comment: despues de preventdefault()  agrega    $('#menu > li > ul > li > a').trigger('click'); los li>ul> li >a dependen del nivel de tu referencia en tu codigo no esta claro este nivel pero primero intenta pegar tal y como lo puse.

Comment: Lo ingresé igual: (function ($) {
    $('.menu li:has(ul)').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#menu > li > ul > li > a').trigger('click'); 

        if ($(this).hasClass('activado')) {

        } else {
            $('.menu li ul').slideUp('slow');
            $('.menu li').removeClass('activado');
            $(this).addClass('activado');
            $(this).children('ul').slideDown('slow');
        }
    });
})(jQuery);

Comment: Pero aún no me direcciona a la vista que le indico.

Comment: una rapida solucion es quitar  e.preventDefault(); eso esta deteniendo el llamado al servidor en tu ref.

Comment: Queda perfecto! Muchas gracias por tu apoyo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solución:

```
(function ($) {
    $('.menu li:has(ul)').click(function (e) {

        $('#menu > li > ul > li > a').trigger('click');

        if ($(this).hasClass('activado')) {

        } else {
            $('.menu li ul').slideUp('slow');
            $('.menu li').removeClass('activado');
            $(this).addClass('activado');
            $(this).children('ul').slideDown('slow');
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```